# Why this LayoutInflater can not achieve current value of widgets?

Tags: android, listview, layout, adapter

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    AdapterFood.get(position).setNumber_of_order(AdapterFood.get(position).getNumber_of_order()+1);
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater=(LayoutInflater)cxt.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View total=layoutInflater.inflate(fragment_shopping_cart,null);
    TextView totaltxt=(TextView)total.findViewById(R.id.total_of_price);
    System.out.println(totaltxt.getText().toString());
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

It is a part of codes of a `ListView` adapter and this click listener is in the method of `getView`. The `cxt` is passed by the constructor.

When I run this code, and press the button, it always output the value that is set in the XML file. I guess this may relate to the `cxt`. Could anyone help me the shoot this problem?

Comment: Well, you are inflating a totally new view rather than using anything visible to the user / you've changed in any of your other code. Where do you set the text of a `R.id.total_of_price` field? How did you get a reference to that `TextView` there?

Comment: You are right. I set R.id.total_of_price in a fragment where I construct a view including this field. Therefore the layoutinflate.inflate is going to build a new view rather than return the view I constructed before..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getLayoutInflater(null);
View total=layoutInflater.inflate(fragment_shopping_cart, parent, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I set R.id.total_of_price in a fragment where I construct a view including this field. Therefore the layoutinflate.inflate is going to build a new view rather than return the view I constructed before..